# how to change the extension of multiple files using bash script?

Tags: bash, batch-rename

I am very new with linux usage maybe this is my first time so i hope some detailed help please.
I have more than 500 files in multiple directories on my server (Linux) I want to change their extensions to .xml using bash script
I used a lot of codes but none of them work some codes i used :

```
for file in *.txt
do
mv ${file} ${file/.txt}/.xml
done
```

or

```
for file in *.*
do
mv ${file} ${file/.*}/.xml
done
```

i do not know even if the second one is valid code or not i tried to change the txt extension beacuse the prompt said no such file '.txt'

I hope some good help for that thank you

Answer (score 8):

#### Explanation

1. For recursivity you need Bash `>=4` and to enable `**` (i.e. `globstar`) ;
2. First, I use [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) to remove the string `.txt`, which must be anchored at the end of the filename (`%`) :
3. the `#` [anchors the pattern](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Substituting_part_of_a_string) (plain word or glob) to the beginning,
4. and the `%` anchors it to the end.
5. Then I append the new extension `.xml`
6. Be extra cautious with filename, you should **[always quote parameters expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)**.

#### Code

This should do it in `Bash` (note that I only `echo`the old/new filename, to actually rename the files, use `mv` instead of `echo`) :

```
shopt -s globstar # enable ** globstar/recursivity
for i in **/*.txt; do
    [[ -d "$i" ]] && continue; # skip directories
    echo "$i" "${i/%.txt}.xml";
done
```

Comment: actually it does change the extension of the bash file just. i am lost here beacuse the bash file with .sh extension not txt. The other files still unchanged

Comment: 1. you got sub-directories ? 2. What kind of file extension should you replace only .txt or others ?

Comment: i want to change all files' extensions in one directory(which has sub-directories) but most of them are .txt

Comment: it does not work it just echo for one time the **/*.txt **/*.xml and if i remove echo it does nothing unfortunately

Comment: can we change the extension without saying .txt imean all extension in a directory

Comment: If all extension should be rename à `.xml`, just use **/* as glob. Otherwise, you want to have a look at mmv (http://ss64.com/bash/mmv.html) or ask a more precise question

Comment: Note that you need to replace `echo` with `mv`.

Comment: It looks like there's a missing semicolon after `continue`.  I tried to edit the answer, but edits by people who aren't the author have to be at least 6 characters long.

Comment: @dfoverdx thanks, I will update. FYI semicolon is not mandatory in script, only if you make it a one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

If its a matter of a one or two sub-directories, you can use the rename command:

```
rename .txt .xml *.txt
```

This will rename all the .txt to .xml files in the directory from which the command is executed.

Comment: Don't recommend `rename` as "rename(1) could be one of three or four different programs -- or you might not have it on your system. A loop or find expression that uses mv is safer."

Comment: For more details see: "How can I rename all my *.foo files to *.bar, or convert spaces to underscores, or convert upper-case file names to lower case?" http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030

Answer (score 1):

If all the files are in same directory, it can be done using a single command. For example you want to convert all jpg files to png, go to the related directory location and then use command

rename .jpg .png *

Comment: poor example... using rename simply renames the files using a new extension.  It definitely doesn't "convert" anything.  After renaming, you would still have files in jpeg format, but named incorrectly with png extension

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to rename "file.txt" to "file.jpg.txt", used rename easy peezy:

rename 's/.txt$/.jpg.txt/' *.txt

man rename will tell you everything you need to know.

Got to love Linux, there's a tool for everything :-)

Answer (score -2):

## passing command line argument for dir path

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $1
names_1=`ls`
for file in ${names_1}
do
mv ${file} ${file}.jpg
done
```

Comment: Please don't parse the output of `ls`, it's broken for file names containing spaces...